# How to get a nicer output in Word from statistical tests using RMarkdown?

Tags: r, r-markdown, psych

Most of the times the results of a statistical test are a `list`. I know that I only can use `kable` with a data frame. The following example is a `Kolmogorov-Smirnov` test (ks.test). There are also many at the `psych` library.
I want to have a nicer output knitting to `Word`. How can this be done with a list like `a`?

````
---
title: "ks test"
output:
  word_document: default
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}
library(knitr)
knitr::opts_chunk$set(echo = TRUE, results="asis")
```


```{r}
x <- rnorm(50)
y <- runif(30)
# Do x and y come from the same distribution?
a <- ks.test(x, y)
a
```
````

Comment: I doubt there's going to be a out of the box way for you to make an arbitrary list into a table that makes sense.

Comment: `broom` from the tidyverse is helpful, but I tend to agree with @cory.  Often, you'll need a bit of DIY to get exactly what you want.

Comment: @Limey Using `tidy` from `broom` the result is not a list but a dataframe, Then, using `kable` becomes possible with nice results. But as you said it is needed some DIY, for example to get the caption of the table.

Answer (score 2):

You can possibly embed a table containing the information from this test?

```r
library(parameters)

x <- rnorm(50)
y <- runif(30)
# Do x and y come from the same distribution?
mod <- ks.test(x, y)

print_html(model_parameters(mod))
```

[image]